# process continous output of synclient

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, python

I am using [synclient](http://linux.die.net/man/1/synclient) to track the position of finger on the touchpad.
I use the following command.

```
synclient -m 100 | awk '{print $2,$3}'
```

This command gives the 'x' and 'y' co-ordinate on the touch-pad.
What I want is, to give these co-ordinates to program which will draw these points. As soon as new point is tracked, it should be drawn. 
But my problem is, since the command generate the output continuously and it has not yet finished, I don't know how to pass the continuous generating output of a command. How to achieve this?
(What I have achieved is the following:

```
timeout 5 synclient -m 100 > pattern
```

So after 5 seconds, 'pattern' file has all the information, I extract the co-ordinates from the file and the draw the lines. But I don't want to do this.)

Comment: I doubt whether bash shell programs (as the author has tagged the question) are suited for plotting graphs. I feel this is best suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: i am going to pass the co-ordinates to a python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that each line shall result in a new drawing. So something like

```
synclient -m 100 |
  while read _ x y; do
    drawprogram $x $y
  done
```

should do. If you get buffering problems then have a look at `stdbuf`.

Comment: not yet eligible to upvote! will surely upvote when eligible!

Comment: @SagarRakshe you can still accept (click on the tick mark to the left of this answer), that way the question is marked as answered.

Comment: @HaukeLaging could you explain what the `_` does please?

Comment: @SagarRakshe The `_` is not by me :-)  I am a bit surprised myself. But the general principle is: bash `read` splits a line in parts, quite similar to what `awk` is doing. So if you need the second and third element you can have bash do this selection and don't need awk any more. If `read` is called with more than one variable name then it assigns the first element to the first variable, the second to the second and so on. If there are more elements than variables all elements which do not get their own variable are put in the last one: `read dummy x y rest`